# How to identify traffic going through akamai

Tags: macos, download

My mac server (10.6.8) is downloading a big file through akamai (a60-254-131-56.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com) despite not having anything on the console (no browser, etc is doing any work)

I know it is probably a download from a big name, like adobe, or even apple.

But how can I tell what it is I'm downloading?

Comment: How do you know that you're downloading a "big file" from akamai? Are you using a network analysis software?

Comment: David - at the router, I see my machine is hogging the bandwidth (point in time), when I'm not doing anything. Then a report on the router shows my bandwidth was about 500meg per hour for about 7 hours. (total time) Then I used the program "net monitor sidekick" to show me what my mac was doing, and it resolves the ip's to names, AND showed me the amount of downloaded data associated with that dns / ip (akamai)